# 500 Internal Server Error instead of 404

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

This is my .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

But when i type a wrong url for example, `http://127.0.0.1:8080/myweb/wrong-url.php`, that doesn't go to 404.html and says 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
any body can explain why?

The error that is showing in my error log is

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. 
Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: The script you are trying to run is failing. Thats really all anyone can tell you from that error. You'll need to check your logs to determine the exact reason for the failure.

Comment: But i don't have any script for the wrong-url.php that is just an example that wrong url is entered, just assume that i have two pages, and home and contact, and i have entered a wrong url, it should go to 404 instead of 500

Comment: Is the .htaccess in the root, or in myweb/? Do you have it in the root, and nother in myweb/?

Comment: @jprofitt its in the myweb directory not in the root, because in my locallhost i have multiple websites so .htacess for this website is in its respective folder

Comment: Do you have access to the error log? It may give you the insight to figure out what the root cause is.

Comment: @jprofitt i am on localserver and i guess there are no error logs on the local server, if there is a way to view error logs on local server please share, i would much appriciate that.

Comment: Generally you can find it as error_log or error.log, depending on the web server you chose

Comment: @jprofitt here is the error that is logged

AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Most of the time that happens when an .htaccess rule keeps pointing itself to itself, or when you have multiple rules that bounce the redirect back and forth. Does the 404.html file exist in your web root, or is it in your myweb/ folder?

Comment: @jprofitt its in the myweb/ folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that your `404.html` page is, itself, generating another 404 because the location is not `/404.html`, but `/myweb/404.html`. Basically it tries to find the `404.html` file, but can't, which generates another 404, then tries to find the `404.html` file, but can't, which generates another 404 etc etc. Change your `.htaccess` to point the 404 to `/myweb/404.html`, or move the file to the root of your server.